# How to prevent Code First from enabling foreign key constraint on a relationship?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first

I have two entities, User and Feedback, and there is one-to-many relationship between those with help of the username field.

```
Feedback --> User 
--------   --------
username   username
```

However, sometimes feedback may code from an unregistered user, and Username field on Feedback will be Null. In that case, the addition of feedback will fail due to the foreign key constraint.

How can I disable the enforcement of a foreign key constraint on a relationship declaratively or by means of the Fluent API? It is enabled by default when the DB is created.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm also looking for an answer to this exact question.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to disable the enforcement of the foreign key constraint for your purpose, you just need to allow NULL values for the foreign key which is called an *optional* one-to-many relationship (in contrast to a *required* relationship which doesn't allow NULL values of the foreign key).

You can define this optional relationship the following way:

```
public class Feedback
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int? UserId { get; set; } 
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Having a nullable type `int?` for the foreign key makes the relationship optional. If `User` has a primary key property named `Id` you can even omit the `[ForeignKey]` attribute because Entity Framework will detect `UserId` as the foreign key of the `User` navigation property based on naming conventions.

Alternatively instead of data annotations you can use Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Feedback>()
    .HasOptional(f => f.User)
    .WithMany() // or WithMany(u => u.Feedbacks)
    .HasForeignKey(f => f.UserId);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for response. What if my primary key (Username) is String and cannot be made nullable? When I specify "public String? Username", I get the following compilation error: The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>'.

Comment: @AlexAvrutin: `String` is a reference type and therefore does allow `null` by default. You don't need to add a `?`.

Comment: But if I do not add ?, I get the foreign key constraint on the relationship enabled by default. I'd like to avoid this. I hope the Fluent API method you kindly mentioned will help me here?

Comment: @AlexAvrutin: EF *always* creates a constraint for a relationship. Why don't you want this? Because a `string` allows `null` by default the relationship will be *optional* and not *required* as explained in my answer. Without a FK constraint in the DB you could have a row with FK "xyz" but no record in the target table with this key "xyz" which is really bad for data consistency in the DB.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will check it again. For some reason, I've got required relationship there.