# Prevent Entity Framework from inferring FK relationships

Tags: ef-code-first, code-first

Simplified example: I have the following POCOs:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int BlogId {get;set;}
}
```

How can I stop Entity Framework (Code First) from inferring the foreign key relationship on Post.BlogId to Blog.Id?

This is a very simplified example but there is a good reason I don't want to infer the FK in my real world example.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to **force** a foreign key, or prevent it from being assumed that it is a foreign key?

Comment: The relationship doesn't have to be required (int?). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324231/how-to-prevent-code-first-from-enabling-foreign-key-constraint-on-a-relationship

Comment: I am looking to prevent EF from creating the FK at all, keeping the field names as in the example but without a relationship

Answer (score 0):

In fact FK relationship for Post.BlogId to Blog.Id will not be inferred in your example! ;)

To get FK for your code it should look either as:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } // This forces FK
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; } // Optional (changes default column name Blog_Id to BlogId)
}
```

or

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; } // This forces FK
    public int BlogId { get; set; } // Optional (changes default column name Blog_Id to BlogId)
}
```

or

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; } // This forces FK
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; } // This forces FK
    public int BlogId { get; set; } // Optional (changes default column name Blog_Id to BlogId)
}
```